# How to embed html file hosted outside the server in an ASP page?

Tags: html, iframe, asp-classic

I have to display the content of an HTML file which is hosted to some other server in a classic ASP page.

I know using #include tage we can embed suchc html file provided they resides in same server, it can not refer to an external urls.

Another way out is to use iFrame, but the problem with that is the user can right click on th page and check URL property of the iFrame, which is not acceptable as the URL where html resides is our third party file hosting environment which we dont want to be exposed for the security purpose.

Note: This html shows some .swf file whic shows some large .flv files hosted on the third party hosting environment.

Any ideas ?

Nikhil

Answer (score 2):

No matter what method you use the end user will be able to see where the request is made, e.g. Fiddler, Firebug. I think iFrame is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try capturing the HTTP stream from the remote page and injecting into your local page. I don't know offhand how to do it in PHP, but you'd use the CFHTTP tag in ColdFusion to accomplish this.